# Accessing prop of dynamically created component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react, teaching myself and am working on a personal project attempting to learn.

I'm currently attempting to make a dynamically generated element that can load a different users profile based on which data has been loaded into the element. For example:

Search 1 Results returns:

User 1 - (click loads User 1's profile)

User 3 - (click loads User 3's profile)

User 5 - (click loads User 5's profile)

This data has been accessed from an object in a json file that has been mapped to return the search results

Currently I've mapped the data to the elements and that works, however when I try to map the ID or name variable to a property and then access it via a console.log and it returns undefined.

I am using Native Base for styling, hence the element names:

```
<Content>
  {this.searchedArray.map(user =>
     <TouchableHighlight key = {user.ID} name = {user.ID} onPress = {() => {console.log(this.props.name)}} >

                       <Card style={{height: 130}}>
                            <Grid>
                                <Row>
                                <Col>
                                    <Image style={{width: 100, height: 100}} source = {{uri: user.photoID}}/>
                                </Col>
                                <Col>
                                <Text>{user.fullName}</Text>
                                </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Grid>
                        </Card>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                )}
            </Content>
```

I expected the output of the console.log to be the user.ID value. This didn't work, I also tried: console.log(user.ID)

However the map function works perfectly and if I were to replace `<Text>{user.fullName}</Text>` with `<Text>{user.ID}</Text>` it would display here.

Can anyone please give me some guidance on this problem, it has stumped me.

Comment: instead of accessing it from `this.props`, capture the `ID` when you iterate over `searchedArray` `console.log(user.ID)`

Comment: Thank you @AsafAviv , however the issue is that grabbed prop data is going to be passed to another function down to load another part of the app. So it needs to be accessible on press.

I appreciate the answer quick response very much though.

Comment: You can pass the prop `ID` to the component you want to render and on `componentDidMount` get the data from the array and save it as state or pass it down to whatever component that needs the data

Comment: @AsafAviv I worked out the problem and you were right originally. My issue was the whole time the database has ID saved as Id and I completely missed it, I guess I was staring at the problem for too long.

Thank you for your help and your method worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this:

```
onClick={() => {console.log(user.ID)}}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response Hamza, however this is not what I am looking for because you cannot add an onClick event it has to be onPress. I have also tried this exact method, but thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: As I said in the comments above I realized that I made the mistake and this works perfectly.

Thank you for taking the time to responding to this question!